# I wrote a very basic quadratic equation code, and it is not returning 'None' as I intend it to.it just prints the correct answer twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```
import math
def quadratic_equation(first_coefficient,
                       second_coefficient,
                       free_coefficient):

    discriminant = (second_coefficient**2) - (4*first_coefficient*free_coefficient)
    first_solution = (-(second_coefficient)+(math.sqrt(discriminant)))/2*first_coefficient
    second_solution = (-(second_coefficient)-(math.sqrt(discriminant)))/2*first_coefficient

    if first_solution != 0 and second_solution != 0:
        return first_solution, second_solution
    elif first_solution != 0 and second_solution == 0:
        return first_solution, None
    elif first_solution == 0 and second_solution != 0:
        return None, second_solution
    elif first_solution == 0 and second_solution == 0:
        return None

print(quadratic_equation(1, -8, 16))
```

so that is my code. The requirement for the assignment is that when there is only one viable answer, it will return the correct one and "None". However, when I run it (by printing), if there is only one viable answer it will just print that answer twice. Can anyone figure out why it is doing that?
thanks, and sorry for being a newb. 
ps--I am only supposed to return it, not print it, and also, the assignment stated that I shouldn't be expecting any negative discriminant so I won't be getting an error code. I don't get any error codes when I print the code, it just isn't returning what I intend it to.

Comment: When I run this code, I get `(4.0, 4.0)` as the output, because the first and second solutions both equal 4.  If that isn't what you want, please explain why.

Comment: Why are you returning None instead of 0 when 0 is a solution? You also haven't handled the case where the discriminant is negative (`math.sqrt` will raise an error).

Comment: Hi-in a case where there is only one solution, as this current program runs, I would like for it to return (4.0, none).

Comment: Also, the 0 returning none is a requirement for the assignment I got in class, not a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just don't do the check you want so you can add one more `elif` after all checks for 0 you have:

```
elif first_solution == second_solution:
    return first_solution, None
```

Also, I'd suggest rewriting all these checks completely to have much clear code i.e.:

```
import math


def quadratic_equation(a, b, c):

    d = (b**2) - (4 * a * c)
    x = [None] * 2

    for i, t in enumerate([1, -1]):
        # t is a sign before discriminant

        # you should never check floating point calculations be equal to the exact numbers more details here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html
        # For some reason you want to have None instead 0, usually that is not the best choise, but here you are: 
        if t * d == b**2:
            x[i] = None
        elif d >= 0:
            x[i] = (-b + t * math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
    # If both solutions are same, just set the second one as None
    if d == 0:
        x[1] = None

    # If for some reason you want to return None instead of (None, None), why not
    if not any(x):
        return None

    return x
```

Comment: thank you very much for your assistance. In terms of my bulky code and word usage, it is a requirement in my course to use "meaningful terms" for parameters and such. I appreciate your help in making my code more understandable.

Comment: If I were to want my math error to return none, how could that be done? in a case where there is a domain issue (if discriminant<0)